# How to extract image width from add_image_size?

Tags: images

How can I extract the width of an image as defined in `add_image_size` for use as a  template variable?

For example if my theme defines the size *small* as `add_image_size( 'small', 195, 146, true );` *195* would be the variable.

I am trying to build a dynamic *mshots* url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, there's no need to do this. However, if it's one added using `add_image_size`, it will be in the $_wp_additional_image_sizes global.

```
global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
echo $_wp_additional_image_sizes['small']['width'];
```

Comment: Thanks @Otto. It was my goal to make the _mshot_ look like the featured image for a _link_ post format. This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This `<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id); ?>`  should return an array of

```
[0] => url
[1] => width
[2] => height
```

Also `wp_get_attachment_metadata` returns the original image size and additional photo data.